# Using Counter with list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, counter

How would I use the Counter in  the collections library to convert a list of lists into a count of the number of times each word occurs overall?

E.g. `[['a','b','a','c'], ['a','b','c','d']] -> {a:2, b:2, c:2, d:1}`

i.e. `a`,`b` and `c` occur in both lists but `d` only occurs in one list.

Comment: Do you have to use the library? This seems simple enough to code.

Comment: Your example is wrong this the answer is wrong: `a` occurs 3 times, not 2 times. The provided answer does not count the *overall* occurrence.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using generator expression with [`set`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> seq = [['a','b','a','c'], ['a','b','c','d']]
>>> Counter(x for xs in seq for x in set(xs))
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Responding to the comment, **Without generator expression**:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for xs in seq:
...     for x in set(xs):
...         c[x] += 1
...
>>> c
Counter({'a': 2, 'c': 2, 'b': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Comment: How you you do it without using list comprehension?

Comment: The example in the original question is wrong: `a` occurs 3 times, not 2 times. The provided answer does not count the *overall* occurrence.

Comment: @displayname, by omitting set call, you will get the desired result.

Comment: @displayname I am getting all 1's when I try that for counts.  It counts how many inner lists contain element 'a' occurs in instead of the the total sum of how many times 'a' occurs.

Comment: I'm struggling to get the intuition behind the list comprehension-looking phrase `x for xs in seq for x in set(xs)`. It seems like `xs` is being iterated over twice. `[[x for xs in p] for x in xs]` is not valid syntax. Can anyone spell it out explicitly?

Answer (score 7):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

seq = [['a','b','a','c'], ['a','b','c','d']]
c = Counter(chain(*seq))

print(c)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

Answer (score 4):

The following code snippet brings all the occurrences' count of the list's item, hope this will help.

```
 from collections import Counter

_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'],['a', 'a', 'g', 'b', 'e', 'g'],['h', 'g', 't', 'y', 'u']]

words = Counter(c for clist in _list for c in clist)
print(words)
```